# Cálculo de preço dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um app web de sistema de vendas, em que pode colocar vários produtos em 1 venda, incrementando `inputs` dinamicamente.

Ele calcula o preço de cada produto multiplicando pela quantidade de forma automática, mas só consigo fazer isso no primeiro `input`. Eu preciso que ele calcule nos outros `inputs`.

Segue o código:

```js
// A função que multiplica o preço do produto pela quantidade:
function calcular_preco_produto() {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_quantidade_venda[]').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('input_preco_venda[]').innerHTML = n1 * 10;
}

// A função que gera inputs dinamicamente:
$(document).ready(function () {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function () {
    i++;

    $('#dynamic_field_venda').append('<tr class= "row" id="row' + i + '"><td><div class="input-field col s6"><input placeholder="Digite o Produto" name="input_produto_venda[]" type="text" class="validate"><label class="active" for="input_produto_venda[]">Produto</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><input placeholder=" " name="input_quantidade_venda[]" id="input_quantidade_venda[]" type="text" class="validate" value="1" onkeyup="calcular_preco_produto()"><label class="active" for="input_quantidade_venda[]">Quantidade</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><div id="input_preco_venda[]"></div><label class="active" for="input_preco_venda[]">Preço</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn btn-danger btn_remove" name="remove" id="' + i + '"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button></div></td> </tr>');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="cadastro_venda" id="cadastro_venda">
       <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field_venda">
             <tr class="row">
                <td>
                   <div class="input-field col s6">
                      <input placeholder="Digite o Produto" name="input_produto_venda[]" type="text" class="validate">
                      <label class="active" for="input_produto_venda[]">Produto</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-field col s2">
                      <input placeholder=" " name="input_quantidade_venda[]" id="input_quantidade_venda[]" type="text" class="validate" value="1" onkeyup="calcular_preco_produto()">
                      <label class="active" for="input_quantidade_venda[]">Quantidade</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-field col s2">
                      <div id="input_preco_venda[]"></div>
                      <label class="active" for="input_preco_venda[]">Preço</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-field col s2">
                      <button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3" id="add" name="add" ><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
                   </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
          <a type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn fonte_button modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons left">attach_money</i>Registrar Venda</a>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Cara dificilmente este código irá funcionar, você repete os `id´s` nos elementos, sendo que em um documento Html, só pode haver um id por elemento!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilize colchetes `[]` em id's. Aliás, nem id's deveria usar, porque os está repetindo ao adicionar um novo elemento. Troque por `class` os id's repetidos. Os colchetes devem vir apenas no atributo `name`.

Evite usar `onkeyup="função()"`. Na minha opinião torna o código mais poluído e ruim de trabalhar, e você nem pode colocar a função chamada dentro do escopo do `.ready`.

Use um evento `keyup` utilizando o jQuery e jogue o valor do cálculo na div com a classe referente ao input, usando o `:eq(índice)` do jQuery. Ou seja, cada input de índice `0` tem uma div com índice `0`, assim como um de índice `1` tem uma div com o mesmo índice.

Resumindo: remova todos os onkeyup's, a função `calcular_preco_produto()`, troque os id's por class, deixe os colchetes apenas nos `name`'s e coloque dentro do `.ready` o event handler abaixo:

```
// A função que multiplica o preço do produto pela quantidade:
$(document).on("keyup", ".input_quantidade_venda", function(){

   // pego o índice da classe
   var indice = $(".input_quantidade_venda").index(this);

    var n1 = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    // aplico a outra classe com o mesmo índice
    $('.input_preco_venda:eq('+indice+')').html(n1 * 10);

});
```

Veja como fica bem mais simples:

```js
// A função que gera inputs dinamicamente:
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   // A função que multiplica o preço do produto pela quantidade:
   $(document).on("keyup", ".input_quantidade_venda", function(){
   
      // pego o índice da classe
      var indice = $(".input_quantidade_venda").index(this);
      
       var n1 = parseInt(this.value, 10);
       // aplico a outra classe com o mesmo índice
       $('.input_preco_venda:eq('+indice+')').html(n1 * 10);
      
   });
   
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function () {
    i++;

    $('#dynamic_field_venda').append('<tr class= "row" id="row' + i + '"><td><div class="input-field col s6"><input placeholder="Digite o Produto" name="input_produto_venda[]" type="text" class="validate"><label class="active" for="input_produto_venda[]">Produto</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><input placeholder=" " name="input_quantidade_venda[]" class="input_quantidade_venda" type="text" class="validate" value="1"><label class="active" for="input_quantidade_venda[]">Quantidade</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><div class="input_preco_venda"></div><label class="active" for="input_preco_venda[]">Preço</label></div><div class="input-field col s2"><button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn btn-danger btn_remove" name="remove" id="' + i + '"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button></div></td> </tr>');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="cadastro_venda" id="cadastro_venda">
    <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field_venda">
          <tr class="row">
             <td>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                   <input placeholder="Digite o Produto" name="input_produto_venda[]" type="text" class="validate">
                   <label class="active" for="input_produto_venda[]">Produto</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                   <input placeholder=" " name="input_quantidade_venda[]" class="input_quantidade_venda" type="text" class="validate" value="1">
                   <label class="active" for="input_quantidade_venda[]">Quantidade</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                   <div class="input_preco_venda"></div>
                   <label class="active" for="input_preco_venda[]">Preço</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                   <button type="button" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3" id="add" name="add" ><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
                </div>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       <a type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn fonte_button modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons left">attach_money</i>Registrar Venda</a>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Puxa, brigadão cara...